# Errata in the original paper on suffix arrays?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, suffix-array

I'm looking at the pseudo-code given in figure 3 of the original paper introducing suffix arrays ["SUFFIX ARRAYS: A NEW METHOD FOR ON-LINE STRING SEARCHES"](http://webglimpse.net/pubs/suffix.pdf).

I can't figure out the logic for lines 4 and 5 (indexing from 0).  The lines reads:

> ***else if*** r < P ***or*** w<sub>r</sub> ≤ a<sub>Pos[N-1]+r</sub> ***then***
>   L<sub>W</sub> ← N

`W` is the pattern of length 'P' we're looking for and `r` is `lcp(A[pos[N-1]:], W)`.  The problem is that in almost all cases, this `lcp` will be less than length of 'W'.  This conditional is meant to handle the case (I think) that the pattern is lexicographically larger than the lexicographically greatest suffix in the array, but it doesn't test this at all.  Lines 2 & 3, on the other hand, which test if `W` is less than the lexicographically smallest suffix seem to make perfect sense

> ***if*** l = P ***or*** w<sub>l</sub> ≤ a<sub>Pos[0]+l</sub> ***then***
>   L<sub>W</sub> ← 0

I believe that the original lines should read something like:

> ***else if*** r < P ***and*** w<sub>r</sub> > a<sub>Pos[N-1]+r</sub> ***then***
>   L<sub>W</sub> ← N

The only way that `W` can be greater than `A[pos[N-1]:]` is if it has an `lcp` shorter than the length of the pattern (otherwise, all of `W` matches and so `W` cannot be greater, only lesser or equal to the thing with which we're sharing the `lcp`) AND if the character after the `lcp` is greater in `W` than in `A[pos[N-1]]`.  Does this seem to make sense?  Is this an error in the original paper?  If not, can someone please explain to me how I'm misinterpreting the original code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you understand the paper correct and in fact it has an error.

Consider the following example: let `A = banana`, `W = nana`. Then `A[pos[N-1]:] = nana`. Algorithm sets `LW = N` or even fails while in fact it's `N-1`.